# Most efficient way to store normals in gltf files?

Tags: gltf

I am looking at most efficient way to store normals in gltf files, we would like to use them for webgl 1 flat and smooth shading. 
Is there support for different normal precision? 
We prefer to not duplicate all vertices in order to have normals because or meshes are huge.

I just found this
KhronosGroup/glTF/blob/master/specification/2.0/README.md#meshes

NORMAL  "VEC3"  5126 (FLOAT)    Normalized XYZ vertex normals

so I assume there is a  single way?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Flat normals**: The most efficient way to store flat normals is to omit them entirely. From the glTF specification, in [the *Meshes* section](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/blob/master/specification/2.0/README.md#meshes),

> "When normals are not specified, client implementations should calculate flat normals."

**Smooth normals**: You are correct, the core glTF specification requires that normals use 5126 / float32 precision. If you need other options, enable the `KHR_mesh_quantization` extension ([extension spec](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/blob/master/extensions/2.0/Khronos/KHR_mesh_quantization/README.md#extending-mesh-attributes)) on your model, which allows for additional types (int16 normalized or int8 normalized). The [gltfpack](https://github.com/zeux/meshoptimizer/tree/master/gltf) library can apply these optimizations automatically, or you can modify the model directly.

Comment: If you are in cesium unfortunately no support for automatic face normals...